# using where to get every other number starting with the last

Tags: c#, linq

I have an array of numbers `{3, 6, 1, 5, 5, 6}` I am trying to get every other number starting with the last number.

The correct result would then be `6, 5, 6` the only way I have been able to get this to work is to use `Reverse`.

```
int[] digitList =  {3, 6, 1, 5, 5,6};
var rev = digitList.Reverse().Where((x, i) => i % 2 == 0).Reverse().ToList();
// Correct results in 6,5,6
var l = digitList.Where((x, i) => i % 2 == 0).ToList();
// Incorrect results in 3,1,5
```

Is there a way of doing this without the Reverse?  How can i tell Where() to start at the other end?

Comment: Why are you forced to use Linq when a simple loop will do your work with a minimal effort?

Comment: If the count is odd, then every other number form the start, if it's even then take every other number from the second one (or skip the first), that removes the need for a reverse operation.

Comment: @DavidG great thinking

Comment: Why are you using a `ToList` ? after `Reverse` that is not needed.

Comment: @Steve there is a lot more going on here this is a MCVE.

Comment: Make a loop that takes every 2nd element (for loop with +2 per itteraton). Offset it by one if hte count is even (%2 result in 0).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the count is odd, then every other number from the start, if it's even then take every other number from the second one (or skip the first), that removes the need for a reverse operation. For example:

```
int[] digitList = { 3, 6, 1, 5, 5, 6 };

//Skip 1 if count is odd, otherwise skip zero
var skipCount = digitList.Count() % 2 == 0 ? 1 : 0;

var l = digitList
    .Skip(skipCount)
    .Where((x, i) => i % 2 == 0)
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to check for *odd/even* length arrays; to amend your current code you 
should change the `== 0` condition:

```
int[] digitList = { 3, 6, 1, 5, 5, 6, 7, 8 };

var rev = digitList
  .Where((x, i) => i % 2 != digitList.Length % 2) // not "== 0"
  .ToList();
```

Comment: @DavidG: Thank you! For sure it should be `!=`